# How to add a multiselect checkbox show/hide values at header columns at UI-GRID(rewritten NG-GRID)

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid

Below is a sample UI-GRID, I toggled the Grid Menu.

I want to achieve having multi-select checkbox values at header column and show/hide the row.. just like in Microsoft Office Excel when table is filtered.. below is a sample screenshot

[image: Microsoft Excel Filtering Function]

I can just select the values I want at the particular column and filter..

Just like the grid menu below, I can show/hide columns and they are enumerated.. but this time, I want row values at a particular column.

[image: Sample UI-Grid with Grid Menu toggled]

Here's my code so far:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope, $timeout) {

var headerTemplate = '<div class="ui-grid-top-panel" style="text-align: center">Transport Orders List</div>';

$scope.filterOptions = {
    filterText: ''
}
$scope.gridOptions = {
    data: 'filteredTransportOrders',
    enableSorting: true,
    pagingPageSizes: [5, 10, 15],
    pagingPageSize: 5,
    columnDefs: [
        {field: 'tpc', displayName: 'TPC', 
            menuItems: [{
                title: 'Values:',
            },
            {
                title: 'Get 1',
                icon: 'ui-grid-icon-check',
                action: '',
                context: ''
            }
            ]
        },
        {field: 'orderdate', displayName: 'Order Date'},
        {field: 'process', displayName: 'Process'},
        {field: 'protectionlevel', displayName: 'Protection Level'},
        {field: 'orderline', displayName: 'Order Line'},
        {field: 'code', displayName: 'Code'},
        {field: 'xdockleg', displayName: 'X Dock Leg'},
        {field: 'origin', displayName: 'Origin'},
        {field: 'xdock', displayName: 'X Dock'},
        {field: 'destination', displayName: 'Destination'},
        {field: 'palletspaces', displayName: 'Pallet Spaces'},
        {field: 'despatchwindowfrom', displayName: 'Despatch Window From'},
        {field: 'despatchwindow', displayName: 'Despatch Window'}
    ],
    filterOptions: $scope.filterOptions,
    enableFiltering: true,
    exporterMenuCsv: false,
    enableGridMenu: true
};


}
```

Thank you for answering!:D

Comment: Do you have any code?

Comment: Yes. Wait. I'll update my post.

Comment: Hi, have you got the answer for this one. please let me know if you got any answer for this questing. And please share with me.  @RJRamirez

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your intention correctly, what you can do to easily show, hide row is to have something like

```
{field: 'orderdate', displayName: 'Order Date', show: true}
```

and in the template, you can do something like

```
<table>
    <tr ng-repeat="row in gridOptions.columnDefs">
        <td ng-show="row.show" ng-bind="row.displayName"></td>
        <td ng-show="row.show" ng-click="row.show = !row.show">Make it hide</td>
        <td ng-show="!row.show" ng-click="row.show = !row.show">Make it show</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/9795/)

[Larger example](http://tak215.github.io/angular-filter-manager/)

Comment: Hi, 

I updated again the question to further illustrate. I want to show/hide the value and the grid is like filtered because if I hide a value in that column, the whole row of data where it belongs will be hidden as well.

Comment: From your example, try adding another column with data. Then what I want to achieve is that when I toggle show/hide the value at a particular column the whole row will be hidden. 
Example:

Col1 | Col2 | Col3
John   Doe    Rocks
Ray    Ban    Dumb
Jay    Parks  Ramp

From Col1, I toggle Ray to hide then the whole row will be hidden.. Col1 Ray, Col2 Ban, Col3 Dumb

There should be a multiselect checkbox at the header of the column that I can just simply toggle the checkbox to filter the grid and show only the values with checked on that particular column

Comment: Okay. So you can use the same logic as this example. You have a property called show which shows the value or not. Now you can add a col and row property for each cell so now there's col and value. When you click on the top of the column, say toggleColumn(3) which calls $scope.toggleColumn(3) and in the controller you can do something like  $scope.toggleColumn = function(col) { yourdata.forEach(function(e){ if(e.col == col) e.show = true; }); } This goes same for the rows.